# Route parameters in middleware NestJS, ExpressJS

Tags: express, nestjs

There is a middleware where I need to retrieve a route path parameter `alias`. The property `params` is present in the request object but the path has not been parsed yet so the parameter is absent.
Maybe this is logical because the middleware process the request before route handler selection so that we can change behavior.
But now I need a route param. How can I get it? The problem is that this parameter is used in many different places of the path that why I can not process it in the same way. I can not retrieve it because I do not know how to get all the route patterns. Does a helper exist? Please give me a tip on how to behave in such a case.

There is [router.param](https://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#router.param) But it does not help. I saw related topics on Github but they are unresolved.

Regards, Victor